# Can't filter properly using a measure as Date in POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

I'm trying to do a report where I have a measure ([10 Days]) with a date stored in it, and I'm using this formula where the measure is necessary as a filter:

```
VOL NEXT 10 DAYS = CALCULATE([SUM VOLUME];FILTER(fOrders; fOrders[Dates] >= TODAY()); FILTER(fOrders; fOrders[Dates] <= [10 Days]))
```

The objective is to get the sum of all the volume (which I did using SUMX) and filter it within today and a specific day.

The [10 Days] has to be a measure because is not 10 days straight, but not counting off days from production.

I created a card and the measure shows the intended date, but when I put at the formula, the output is wrong. And if I put the date in the format `DATE(YYYY;MM;DD)` it works just fine. But I tried `DATE(YEAR([10 Days]);MONTH([10 Days]);DAYS([10 Days]))` and the sum was still using the wrong date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the measure value to a variable and then apply the filter. The following calculation should get you started:

```
Volume Sum = 
       VAR EndDate = [10 Days]
Return CALCULATE(SUM(fOrders[Volume]),fOrders[Dates]>=TODAY()&&fOrders[Dates]<=EndDate)
```

*Note: The above formula is written under the assumption that [10 Days] is always higher than today. If it's not then modify the formula accordingly.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked just fine! Thanks a lot! But can you explain why using the "VAR" solves the issue? I couldn't grasp the concept of VAR is powerBI yet.

Comment: In this scenario, using VAR limits the measure to one value (otherwise you could have different values for each column). VAR has different uses in different contexts. Hopefully the following link will clarify some of your doubts https://www.kasperonbi.com/use-more-variables-in-dax-to-simplify-your-life/